# I have to transfer few objects from my development server to production server using Save file

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, iseries-navigator

I have to transfer few objects from AS400 dev server to prod server.
There is a Logical file which I newly created and PF of this LF is available in production, So I don't need to transfer PF to production.

1) Using SAVOBJ I have copied the LF to save file, If I restore this LF in prod server, will it automatically point to the PF in production ? Or Do I need to recompile the source of LF in production to point to Prod PF ?

2) If I want to recompile the LF in production then how can I copy the source of LF to save file ?

3) I want to copy a new PF with data to save file. If I do SAVOBJ command will to copy the data as well with the object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) yes. My PF are in the same lib as my LF. I use [SAVRSTOBJ](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/cl/savrstobj.htm) in the same lib as the PF. It combines save on the source server and restore on the target server.  Use DSPDBR YOUR_PF to check your PF -> LF attachment.

2) You can transfer your source file with SAVRSTYOBJ too

3) yes data are saved with the object

Answer (score 0):

2. The easiest option would be to open the source member in RDi and copy-and-paste into a source member on the target server.  If you really need a SAVF, you'll have to save the source PF, and then restore it.  SAVOBJ has a parameter for FILEMBR that should let you save only that single member.
3. Yes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the source file transfer entirely with OS tools, I'd recommend to pair both machines with SNA over Enterprise Extender (crtctld type *APPC), configure SNADS, see [here](https://kb.pocnet.net/wiki/AS/400_SNADS_Konfiguration) for a german text regarding this topic. Use Google or so to translate. After that you can use sndnetf for most easy transfer of file members or SAVF's. Initial work is considerable, but after that it's less cumbersome than FTP.

Considering LF, I'd sndnetf and recompile the LF on the prod server, because that seems to me the last cumbersome method.